# MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE not recognized

Tags: android, camera, media

I'm having trouble with the resource on android developers for the camera, here is my code:

```
// create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

// create a file to save the image
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file name
// start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

The problem is 'MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE' which says that it can not be resolved to a variable. I got mediastore, camera and URI imported into my project. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16):

Try importing [`android.provider.MediaStore.Files.FileColumns`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.html) and change `MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE` to `FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE`.

If you are using the sample code from Android developers blog be sure to check the section about [saving media files](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media), there you have the constants created to handle that.

Answer (score 5):

Quession: MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE not recognized

Anwser: Please add row in your class

```
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
```

Comment: I didn't understand this answer until I found this code here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media

Answer (score 2):

if you are trying the camera example from the android guide then read this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media
they have declared the method at the bottom of the documentation

Comment: `public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you didn't give the good permissions in your Manifest (such as Camera access, external storage access, etc.)